# Does depression have a big impact on an individual's exercise results?

Tags: doms

I have been depressed before, but I don't believe I have any ongoing, persistent issue with it, though I wouldn't check it off my list. My most prominent issues are social anxiety disorder, which seems to have an impact in exercise due to almost constant anxiety, up and down elations of mood, and some self-image & self-confidence issues.

There are bodybuilders who have said they suffer from depression with amazing results, so this kind of boggles the typical, straightforward "yes" answer, because some have succeeded well in exercise while being depressed.

So to what degree does depression, anxiety/stress, etc. get in the way of results?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are depressed to the point where you just don't work out at all, or don't try, I am not aware of any negative that depression has on the effects of working out, at least by itself. Most of the studies around show that exercise has a beneficial effect on depression and can help alleviate/prevent depressive bouts.

Where you might be getting an impact is in the anxiety disorder, which can result in increased levels of cortisol due to stress. Cortisol is catabolic in nature (Meaning it breaks down muscle rather than building it), so high levels of this from stress could be undermining your efforts. I believe cortisol is also associated with lowered levels of natural anabolic hormones in the body, but that is from memory only, I haven't looked it up yet.